# Complex number basics

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|z_1|$=1 and $|z_2|$=1, and $|\frac{1}{z_1}+\frac{1}{z_2}|=\frac{3}{2}$, then what would be the value of $2|z_1+z_2|$?

I tried direct substitution but it didn't work for me. Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\left|\frac{1}{z_1} + \frac{1}{z_2}\right| = \left|\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_1z_2}\right| = \frac{|z_1 + z_2|}{|z_1||z_2|}$$

Comment: Shouldn't $z_1+z_2$ be equal to $\frac{3}{2}$ from here?

Comment: @Zlatan $|z_1 + z_2| = \frac 32$ But that's not the same as $z_1 + z_2$. Luckily, the question only asks you to find the former (or actually, *twice* the former, so it's a nice round answer).

Comment: I don't get it Deepak. Can you please explain me the whole concept. Please I really need to get good at complex numbers and your help is just what Im looking for.

Comment: $|z_1 + z_2|$ is the magnitude of the sum of the two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$. It's a purely real and non-negative quantity. It's quite clearly distinct from $z_1 + z_2$. This is what I meant. Just taking an example, when you add the complex numbers $3$ ($z_1$) and $4i$ ($z_2$), you get $3 + 4i$ ($z_1 + z_2$). The magnitude of that is $\sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = 5$ ($|z_1 + z_2|$). Is that what you're uncertain about?